# API gateway (Ocelot) and Aggregator .NET core microservices architecture pattern using RabbitMQ/ActiveMQ

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices, api-gateway, ocelot, aggregator

In our application, we adopted a microservices architecture pattern. I am bt familiar with microservices architecture but I have a few doubts:
API Gateway: Userful to have a single point of entry to connect with all microservices and on top of that we can enable other features like routing, aggregates, load balancing, etc. for this we are using Ocelot API gateway.
Aggregator: There are many scenarios where, we need to call multiple services, fetch the data and combine them into an API response.

I would like to know, should we use API Gateway and Aggregator?
Also, I checked Ocelot documentation and Ocelot does provide the Aggregate feature but only for GET calls. but in our API implementation, we have a POST call to fetch the data.

also, Just wanted to confirm, that we have ActiveMQ in place for asynchronous communication between services mostly when we have transactional data.
so, should this transactional communication also be taken care of by the Aggregator service or from the API gateway?

I would really like to understand if my reasoning is correct here.

Thank you in advance!